# Hashed primary key

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table `library` where each row represents a music track. I want to make the primary key be the track's audio fingerprint. Unfortunately SQLAlchemy passes me a postgres error when I try to insert:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) index row size 3384 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "library_fingerprint_key"
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

I now want to store the full fingerprint as a normal column and create a hashed version to be the primary key. I've tried using SQLAlchemy's [Context-Sensitive Default Functions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions) for this but I still get the above error msg.

Is there a way to automatically hash the primary key based on another column (the fingerprint column)?

Code snippet below

```
def fingerprint_md5(context):
        return hashlib.md5(context.current_parameters['fingerprint']).hexdigest()
```

class Library(Base):
    **tablename** = 'library'
    track_hash = Column(String, primary_key=True, default=fingerprint_md5)
    fingerprint = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)

Updated for index DDL:

```
Indexes:
    "library_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (track_hash)
    "library_fingerprint_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (fingerprint)
    "library_path_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (path)
```

Comment: What's the DDL of your index? It sounds like it may be encompassing more than just the hash, since if it was truly indexing just the md5, I don't see how the index row size could ever be 3384.

Comment: That error is from trying to insert the original fingerprint (not the hash of it), which is a very long alphanumeric string.

Comment: OK, but I think that makes my question all that much more important -- what is the DDL for that index? It seems like it may be trying to index more than you are intending...

Comment: @khampson I added the index info, let me know if you were after something else.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the fingerprint value I was trying to insert was too long to be an index (primary key or otherwise). The solution was to insert the full fingerprint into a normal column with no unique constraint, and then calculate the md5 hash for the primary key `track_hash` using the code in my OP.